# How to cross-compile for aarch64 using clang?

Tags: clang, cross-compiling, arm64

I want to cross-compile for aarch64 using clang, but I got an error.

I worked on Ubuntu 16.04.

I compiled the source file with command:

```
clang -target aarch64 -B/home/xxx/op-tee-v8/toolchains/aarch64/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ 1.cpp
```

1.cpp is the file that I want to cross compile.

Then I got an error:

```
/home/xxx/op-tee-v8/toolchains/aarch64/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_x86_64

Supported emulations: aarch64linux aarch64elf aarch64elf32 aarch64elf32b aarch64elfb armelf armelfb aarch64linuxb aarch64linux32 aarch64linux32b armelfb_linux_eabi armelf_linux_eabi

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu, this installs the right linker needed. You might also need to install libc6-arm64-cross, libc6-dev-arm64-cross, crossbuild-essential-arm64.

Answer (score 0):

- `aarch64` ~= `arm64`
- here on Mac, using `clang` to build for `arm64`

  - `clang -arch arm64 main.c -o main_arm64`
- maybe your case should be:

  - `clang -arch arm64 ... 1.cpp`